# Python subprocess.Popen fails with multiple arguments involving double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a simple Python script which live prints the output of commands. Following is the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

def RunSubProcess(process, process_args):
    process = subprocess.Popen([process, process_args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    while process.stdout.readable():
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print(line.strip())

# Below works for an example since it is a simple command with one argument
RunSubProcess('ls', '-la')

# But below does not work because of multiple args and double qoutes involved
RunSubProcess('grep', '-r "Some_String" .')
```

**Question:**
As you can see, I have a reusable method called `RunSubProcess` which takes the command as the first parameter and the arguments to the command as second parameter.

`RunSubProcess` works well for `ls -la` which is a simple command. But `RunSubProcess` fails when I want to call `grep -r "Some_String" .`. I believe this `subprocess.Popen` failing because there is more than one parameter involved in the command and especially `"`s.

How can I pass `process_args` properly by ensuring the double quotes and multiple arguments are taken care of?

**Environment:**
I am running this Python script on a bash shell on macos with Python 3.9.0 installed.

Comment: You are calling `grep` with a *single* parameter, which is `-r "Some_String" .`.  If you're going to pass a list to `subprocess.Popen()`, you have to have all the parameters as individual items in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function definition is weird. A more sane design would be to accept a list just like `subprocess.Popen` and simply pass it on verbatim.

Tangentially, this looks like you should simply use `subprocess.run()` instead. If you don't particularly care about the output, just run the process and let it write directly to standard output, without passing through Python at all.

```py
subprocess.run(['ls', '-la'])
subprocess.run(['grep', '-r', 'SomeString', '.'])
```

If you do want the output to be visible to Python, use `print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-la'], text=True))` or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be great if you could please modify the answer to demonstrate how to fix `RunSubProcess`. I am using `grep` as an example here but I need to run much more complex long running commands. For this I have made `RunSubProcess` spit the output in a live manner. I should make `RunSubProcess` to accept a list and pass it on? Let me try.

Comment: `RunSubProcess('grep', ['-r', "Some_String", '.'])` doesn't work. I get the following error - `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple`

Comment: `print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-la']))` ignores honouring newlines in the output. I have already taken care of this in my reusable method `RunSubProcess` you see? Hence I wish to fix this in `RunSubProcess` which takes care of other things as well.

Comment: It does not ignore newlines, but I needed to add `text=True` to the argument list; updated now.  Your previous comment pertains to code which I already removed from the answer before you commented.  Encapsulating the call to `subprocess` is fine, of course, but `subprocess.run()` and its variations already takes care of everything which you are doing in your function, so it really does seem superfluous.

Comment: The last edit you did resolves the issue. Thanks a lot to you :D